# Python issue with virtual environment

Tags: python, django

I set up Django CMS project and I created my first blog. When running the server I am opening http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog by default. I saved it in my Projects folder. Now I want to test Wagtail CMS but I cannot open the page because it is changing my localhost page from http://127.0.0.1:8000 to http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog and I get an error Page not found. I can only access admin panel and nothing more. I removed all environments and reinstalled all packages from scratch but it didn't help.

I tried to create Django quickstart project and I have the same issue. Whenever running command `python.manage.py runserver` it redirects me to  http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog and I get the same error which is 404 Not Found.

I was following [these steps](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/01-install.html) when installing Django CMS.

Edit: The same issue is with Docker. Whenever I migrate the data from quickstart project and run it it redirects me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Did you make any changes in settings file?

Comment: Not really, just migrated and tried to run